# Hosting a server behind a repeater router

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys WRT54G router running the DD-WRT firmware and I have it configured to act as a repeater of an existing wireless AP. I have permission to repeat the primary router's wireless signal, however, I do not have the authority to create port forwarding rules on the primary router. I want to run a server (server is connected via ethernet cable to one of the LAN ports on the repeater router). If I don't have access to create port forwarding rules on the primary router, would it be possible in some other way (on my end) to still allow clients outside of the LAN to connect to the server?

Comment: Sure, using VPN. But that means you need an external VPN server. What services are you even trying to provide? 11g is super slow by today's standards.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way I could think of is to use something like teamviewer or logmein to enable people to login to a desktop on the server itself. Without port-forwarding you can't use more professional methods.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** If the "edge" router (the one closest to the Internet) is not allowing you to open ports, you can't just *open ports anyway*. Just like you can't walk into a house if you are outside and there are two doors; the outer one is locked; and the inner one is wide open. Doesn't matter how open you make the inner door; you still have to get past the outer door.

The only way to offer "listening" services from a computer behind a router like this, without opening ports and assuming things like NAT-T don't work (they generally don't), is to have a third-party server that acts as an interposer between your local server and the Internet. The interposer server would have to sit on the public Internet with the ability to open ports (ideally it'd have a static IP, too).

Depending on exactly what kind of server you want to host, and how the technology of that server works, would dictate what kind of technology you use for the interposer server:

- If you're just hosting web traffic (HTTP(S)), you can use a reverse proxy like nginx or squid on the interposer.
- If you're hosting a custom protocol like a game or something, in most cases you need something that bridges remote hosts to a private subnet at layer 3, allowing arbitrary transport layers (e.g. UDP). Hamachi VPN is a good example of that.